# Is it possible to have messages with multiple lines in translation files of Yesod?

Tags: haskell, internationalization, yesod

I am doing i18n in a Yesod scaffolded application as instructed in the following links: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/i18n-messages-in-the-scaffolding, https://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization and http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2016-04-19/shakespeare-2.0.8.1/Text-Shakespeare-I18N.html

It looks like an `en.msg` file like:

```
Hello: Hello World!
MultilineText: 
  line 1.
  line 2.
  etc...
SingleLine: A single line message.
```

is not supprted, because of the **MultilineText** definition. Is this true or there is a way/syntax to do this?

Comment: You could open an issue at https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/issues for it.

Comment: Did that @Qwertie thanks https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/issues/215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the source, no, it is not possible:

```
loadLangFile :: FilePath -> IO [Def]
loadLangFile file = do
    bs <- S.readFile file
    let s = unpack $ decodeUtf8 bs
    defs <- fmap catMaybes $ mapM (parseDef . T.unpack . T.strip . T.pack) $ lines s
    return defs
```

The `parseDef` function operates on the result of `lines` call, which splits the file contents by newline character.